# How do I update this recursive function to check the property name of an object?

Tags: javascript, json

I found the following snipped of code online, it very accurately and recursively removes properties from an object if the values are null, undefined, or 0

```
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
        (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(obj[key]) ||
        (obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === null || obj[key] === 0) && delete obj[key]
    );
    return obj;
};
```

I'm trying to modify it so that it also check the a property name for a value of "index". If it matches, do not delete the property even if it's value is 0

For example, if the following object is processed

```
"page": {
 "index": 0,
 "title": "test",
 "credits": undefined 
}
```

the desired result would be

```
"page": {
 "index": 0,
 "title": "test"
}
```

the current actual result is

```
"page": {
 "title": "test", 
}
```

Comment: Just replace `obj[key] === 0` by `key !== "index" && obj[key] === 0`? Or use `key !== "index" && (` _the rest of the conditions_ `)`.

Comment: or you write `key === "index" || ....rest` but maybe you want to insert this condition between the two lines `... removeEmpty(obj[key]) || key === "index" || (obj[key] === undefined ...` you see the difference? If this is too obscure for you, then it may be better to rewrite the function properly. There are two `if()`s in there and the respective actions if the condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

You can define some protected keys and exclude them from the deletion process:

```js
const protectedKeys = ['index'];

const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj)
      .forEach(key =>
          (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && removeEmpty(obj[key]) ||
          (obj[key] === undefined || obj[key] === null || obj[key] === 0)
          && protectedKeys.includes(key) === false
          && delete obj[key]
      );
      
      return obj;
};

const data = {
  "page": {
   "index": 0,
   "title": "test",
   "credits": undefined 
  }
};

console.log(removeEmpty(data));
```